# How do I create a batch script that will delete a folder on a scheduled basis?

Tags: windows, scripting

#### Exact Duplicates:

- [How to write a batch file to delete the files which are 5 days or older from a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661447/)
- [write a batch file to delete 6 days older files from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662607/)
- [write a batch file to delete 5 daya older files from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659770/)
- [How do I write a batch file to delete folders and files on a time basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625613/)
- [write a batch file to remove the folders by date and time wise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613803/)
- [write a script to delete files from a folder which are 5 days older than current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658717/)

How do I create a batch script that will delete a folder on a scheduled basis?

Answer (score 3):

Write a batch script to delete the file

```
rd <YOURDIR>
```

and then schedule it in Windows Tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch to delete the file and then place it on a scheduled task on a server or workstation.

Answer (score 0):

In a text editor do the following

```
@echo off
rd <enter your directory name here>
```

Save the file as filename.bat

Create a scheduled task and select the batch file as the file to run.

Answer (score 0):

You write your batch file and then, even better than using the Scheduler manually, you can use the **at** command to schedule the .bat file to run periodically.

The advantage of this is that you can put your final **at** command in a second bat file for easier distribution to your target systems.

[**at** reference page on help.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)