# How do I write a batch file to delete folders and files on a time basis?

Tags: scripting, batch-file

#### Exact Duplicates:

- [How to write a batch file to delete the files which are 5 days or older from a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661447/)
- [write a batch file to delete 6 days older files from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662607/)
- [write a batch file to delete 5 daya older files from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659770/)
- [How do I create a batch script that will delete a folder on a scheduled basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615008/)
- [write a batch file to remove the folders by date and time wise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613803/)
- [write a script to delete files from a folder which are 5 days older than current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658717/)

I want write a  batch file to delete folders, subfolders and temporary files on time basis.

The conditions are like this:

- I need to delete the file from folder one hour before to current running time.
- I want to get the current time from system and delete the one hour before files
- The file format is like this: `<file name> <date>`
- The time format is `dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm` or `dd-mm-yy-hh-mm`

Comment: See <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613803/write-a-batch-file-to-remove-the-folders-by-date-and-time-wise/614461#614461">this</a> answer and adapt accordingly. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: They clearly aren't "exact" because they all have different titles ;)

Answer (score 2):

Batch can be surprisingly powerful but I don't think the kind of date manipulation you want will be practical.

You can use `FOR` to split the date into elements and then use `SET /A` to do the subtraction, but then you're going to need a huge number of `IF` and `GOTO` statements to handle cases like subtracting an hour from half past midnight on the 1st of January.

I think you'd be better off investigating [VBS](http://www.mhuffman.com/notes/language/vbs_intro.htm) or [Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this script to delete files from a folder that are older than 1 hour.

```
# Script Delete1Hour.txt
var str folder, list, file
cd $folder
lf -n "*" $folder ($ftype=="f") AND ( $fmtime < addtime(diff("-10000")) ) > $list
while ($list <> "")
do
    lex "1" $list > $file
    system del ("\""+$file+"\"")
done
```

This is biterscripting. The important command is

```
lf -n "*" $folder ($ftype=="f") AND ( $fmtime < addtime(diff("-10000")) )
```

Which tells biterscripting - give me all entries in folder $folder with names that match the patten "*" whose file type is "f" (flat file, not directory), and whose file modification time ($fmtime) is earlier than 1 hour. See the documentation for the lf command at http://www.biterscripting.com/helppages/lf.html .

Save the script in file C:/Scripts/Delete1Hour.txt, run it as

```
script  "C:/Scripts/Delete1Hour.txt" folder("C:/testfolder")
```

It will delete all files from C:/testfolder that are older than 1 hour.